# I'm trying to send protocol buffer message to server several times but server only got the first one

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to send protocol buffer message to server several times but server 
only got the first one, the output is like this

```
 msgContent:
 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

and this thing only show once when I think it should show ten times
anyone can help me ? thanks very much..

```
//server
  public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
      Thread serverThread = new Thread() {
        private ServerSocket server;

        @Override
        public void run() {
          try {
            while(true) {
              try {
                if (server == null) {
                  server = new ServerSocket(8080);
                }
                Socket client = server.accept();
                InputStream is = client.getInputStream();
                TestProto.Test test = TestProto.Test.parseDelimitedFrom(is); 
                System.out.println("msgContent: \n" + test.getId());

              } catch (Exception ex) {
              }
            }
          } catch (Exception ex) {
          }
        }
      };
      serverThread.start();
    }
  }

  ///////////////////////////////////////client
  public class Client {


    private static void sendProtoc(){
      try {
        TestProto.Test test = TestProto.Test.newBuilder().setId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").build();
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8080);
        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
        int msgType = 1;
        test.writeDelimitedTo(os);
        os.flush();
      } catch (Exception ex) {
      }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        sendProtoc();
        System.out.println("sent " + i);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sockets should be closed when you no longer need it.

Comment: I guess that the messages are concatenated, and that the deserializer only parses the first message. You can check that by printing the serialized messages on the sender and reception side.

Also see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32182035/set-maximum-size-of-protobuf-object) on how to possibly solve it, if it is indeed the problem.